# "The operator '[]' isn't defined" error when using .data[] in flutter firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am learning to use firestore in flutter following Net Ninja's tutorial on youtube. After user authenticatin was done this guy added user records to the database whenever a new user is created, for doing this a new model was added passing 1 String named "name" and from what I undertstood for calling that he mapped the model and then used .data['name'] to get that string from the model(string was called name) and when doing this, I got the error `The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Map<String, dynamic> Function()'` Why am I getting this error?

username model

```
class Username {
  final String name;
  Username({ this.name });
}
```

databse.dart file (the following code is wrapped in a class called DatabaseService)

```
  List<Username> _usernameListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc){
      return Username(
        name: doc.data['name'] ?? '',
      );
    }).toList();
  }
```

auth.dart

```
  Future registerWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      User user = result.user;

      // create a new document for the user with uid
      await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).updateUserData('user123');
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } catch(e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

if you have any questions or need to see more code, please let me know in the comments

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Change this:

```
name: doc.data['name'] ?? ''
```

Into this:

```
name: doc.data()['name'] ?? ''
```

`data()` is a method now therefore you have to add `()`, from the source code:

```
  Map<String, dynamic> data() {
    return _CodecUtility.replaceDelegatesWithValueInMap(
        _delegate.data(), _firestore);
  }
```

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore/lib/src/document_snapshot.dart#L38

Answer (score 13):

For me, worked like this:

```
return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
  return Todo(
    // before
    title: doc.data()['title'],
    // after
    title: (doc.data() as dynamic)['title'],
  );
}).toList();
```

In pubspec.yaml:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
...
cloud_firestore: ^2.3.0
firebase_core: ^1.3.0
```

Comment: This line save my day, Thanks!!: title: (doc.data() as dynamic)['title']

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Firestore's `data` used to be a property of `QueryDocumentSnapshot`, but now it is a function, `data()`.

And, as the error message suggests, what you are dealing with is indeed a `Map<String, dynamic>` **`Function()`**, i.e. a function that returns a map.

So, simply add empty parentheses to call the function `data`:

```
doc.data()['name']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can tag doc.data() as dynamic and use it. So that your code can look like this

```
// brew list from snapshot
  List<Brew> _brewListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
      dynamic data = doc.data();

      return Brew(
          name: data['name'] ?? '',
          sugars: data['sugar'] ?? '0',
          strength: data['strength'] ?? 0);
    }).toList();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
messageText = message['text'];
```

This syntax should work with any updated plugins you use.

Answer (score -1):

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: _fireStore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot){
            if(!snapshot.hasData){
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                // ignore: missing_return
                backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                ),
              );
            }
            final messages = snapshot.data.docs;
            List<Text> messageWidgets = [];
            for(var message in messages){
              final messageText = message.data()['text'];
              final messageSender = message.data()['sender'];
              final messageWidget = Text('$messageText from $messageSender');
              messageWidgets.add(messageWidget);
            }

            return Column(
              children: messageWidgets,
            );
          }
        ),
```

Comment: i have tried but it showing the same error line on 
final messageText = message.data();
final messageSender = message.data()['sender'];

Comment: try: message['text'] and message['sender'] . Done

Answer (score -1):

yes, you should try message['text']

Comment: Hi there, I see you are new
Please be more specific and add Code snippet when answering questions.