# firebase mapping error for the flutter project

Tags: firebase, flutter

```
Widget searchList() {
 return ListView.builder(
 itemCount: searchSnapshot.docs.length,
   itemBuilder: (context, index) {
     return SearchTile(
     userName: searchSnapshot.docs[index].data["name"],
     userEmail: searchSnapshot.docs[index].data["email"],
     );
     });
  }
```

The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Map<String, dynamic> Function()'.
Try defining the operator '[]'.

I am getting this error Please help me with that

Comment: signingUp() {
    if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> userInfoMap = {
        "name": userNameTextEditingController.text,
        "email": emailTextEditingController.text
      };


here is the map function

Comment: Are you using Document or Query Snapshot? https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#document--query-snapshots

Comment: I am using query snapshot.
but still getting that error
I am new to this thing

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["The operator '\[\]' isn't defined" error when using .data\[\] in flutter firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63529174/the-operator-isnt-defined-error-when-using-data-in-flutter-firestore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error after updating firebase related packages of my project right now.

Simple fix is to change

```
searchSnapshot.docs[index].data["name"]
```

to

```
searchSnapshot.docs[index].data()["name"]
```

so to add the () behind data.

It seams like google changed the syntax to fit better together with the admin sdk in firebase cloud functions or any other backend.

Source: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore/lib/src/document_snapshot.dart#L38 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/63529675/3917673

Answer (score 0):

Do this,

```
Widget searchList() {
 return ListView.builder(
 itemCount: searchSnapshot.docs.length,
   itemBuilder: (context, index) {
     return SearchTile(
     userName: searchSnapshot.docs[index].data()["name"],
     userEmail: searchSnapshot.docs[index].data()["email"],
     );
     });
  }
```

Calling [] has been deprecated, now, you'll have to use `.data()` method.

Comment: Please upvote and accept this as the answer, if this helped :)

Comment: The getter 'data' isn't defined for the type 'QuerySnapshot'.
Try importing the library that defines 'data', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'data'.


Now this error is coming

Comment: I have updated my answer :)