# Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting this error not sure where the problem is the codes look ok but

---

```
  ActivityFeedItem(
      {this.username,

      this.userId,
      this.type,
      this.mediaUrl,
      this.mediaId,
      this.userProfileImg,
      this.commentData});

  factory ActivityFeedItem.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot document) {

    var data = document.data();
    return ActivityFeedItem(
      username: data['username'],
      userId: data['userId'],
      type: data['type'],
      mediaUrl: data['mediaUrl'],
      mediaId: data['postId'],
      userProfileImg: data['userProfileImg'],
      commentData: data["commentData"],
    );
```

lib/comment_screen.dart:164:21: Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.

- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
  Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
  username: data['username'],
  ^
  lib/comment_screen.dart:165:19: Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.
- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
  Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
  userId: data['userId'],
  ^
  lib/comment_screen.dart:166:20: Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.
- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
  Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
  comment: data["comment"],
  ^
  lib/comment_screen.dart:167:22: Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.
- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
  Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
  timestamp: data["timestamp"],
  ^
  lib/comment_screen.dart:168:22: Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.
- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
  Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
  avatarUrl: data["avatarUrl"],
  ^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: What does ```data``` look like?  What is its type?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Please try this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63529174/the-operator-isnt-defined-error-when-using-data-in-flutter-firestore and also does the reference of data in data['username'] takes you to var data. or inside document.data();

Comment: @kaxp the reference takes me to var data

and I also tried document.data()[username] and no change

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data();
```

Comment: I have tried that as well unfortunately didn't work. 

I have included the error codes from terminal, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

You should change var --> Map as follows:
Somehow Dart does not recognize data as Map at compile time.

```
Map data = document.data();
```

Comment: I added the error codes I am getting at terminal

I tried map it just removed the error red lines after data but the same error were produced in terminal