# i have this problem with getting data from API request

Tags: http, dart

I have this problem with getting data from API request
it appears only on the (price) argument:

_TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'double')

Comment: Please don't post photos of code. Paste it into your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

price argument should be replaced by [‘Price’]`price: snapshot[index] [‘Price’]`

Comment: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>'.
Try defining the operator '[]'.

Comment: could that be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63529174/the-operator-isnt-defined-error-when-using-data-in-flutter-firestore