# How to get value with key from a Map<String, dyanmic> in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to flutter and Firestore, and still leaning.

I have been trying to print a single value from a Map<String, Dynamic>. When I print the whole map it works but when tried to print a single value with key, it produces a null error.

```
getUsersFromFireStore(String appUid) async {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> list = [];
    await instance.collection('Users').where('refDocument', isEqualTo: appUid).get()
        .then((querySnapshotOne) {
      return querySnapshotOne.docs[0].reference.collection('Data').orderBy('timeStamp', descending: true).get();
    }).then((querySnapshotTwo) {
      if(querySnapshotTwo.size > 0){
        querySnapshotTwo.docs.forEach((doc) {
          String id = doc.id;
          list.add(doc.data()); // Here is the problem
          // print(doc.data().toString()); produces {age:24, name: Hari Ram}
          // But doc.data()['name'] doesn't work, gives null error
        });
      }
    });
    return list;
}
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

** UPDATE ** when tried with `doc.data['name']` as per the comments, it shows following error:

[image]

Comment: can you post data saving code so that I can test it as well

Answer (score 2):

doc.data['name'] // This should solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it didn't work. Screenshot has been added in original question.

Comment: In your screenshot, you are using “doc.data[‘name’]” instead of “doc.data()[‘name’]”. Since data is a [function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63529174/16929894), it requires parenthesis. Can you confirm if you still see an error after adding the parenthesis? The “get()” function would also work as per the documentation [available](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/16243c543fdf50ec1dd8cc1b5e0d153788a903d2/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore/lib/src/document_snapshot.dart#L47).

Answer (score 0):

Remove () after the data keyword.
i.e. `print(doc.data['name'])`

UPDATE :
Try `doc.get('name')`

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it didn't work. Screenshot has been added in original question.

Comment: can you upload the screenshots of ```print(doc.data())``` and ```print(doc.data()["name"])```